# Heroku Site with DNS on Media Temple

Tags: heroku, dns, cname, mediatemple

I have a old site in PHP that is hosted on media temple. but i want to add a admin area in rails hosted on HEROKU.

i am trying to set follower the sub-domain name admin.mysite.com to heroku.

on my media temple account i go to  **Edit Zone File : mysite.com** 
I add a new row

> Name = admin Type = cname  data = mysite.herokuapp.com

but when i go to mysite.herokuapp.com it works fine but when i go to admin.mysite.com i get Heroku | No such app

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom domain to your Heroku app. See this Dev Center guide, [Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

Essentially:

```
$ heroku domains:add  admin.mysite.com --app my_app
```